# Opening links in stock browser instead of webview from an iframe

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, iframe

I'm trying to open links from an app using the OS's stock browser. However, the linked website always opens in the app's webview of the app. The links are placed within a website that loads into the app using an iframe.

Is there any way to force the links to open in the set stock browser (iOS/Android) just changing the content of the website itself? Unfortunately I don't have control over the app itself or anything outside the iframe.

I already tried using different link targets ("_blank", "_top", etc.) without any changes in the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Only thing I can think of is `target="_parent"`. I'm not really familiar with mobile stock browsers, so sorry if that doesn't help.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. However, nothing changed when setting the parameter and the link still opens in the webview.

Comment: Well, if it's really frame/iframe it should work, but problem probably lies within app itself. I hope someone else will be able to help you :)